# Querying path structure information using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider I have a table with a lot of paths like:

- \test
- \test\file.txt
- \test\file2.txt
- \file3.txt
- \test\subfolder\anotherfolder\test.txt

How would perform a SELECT query that accurately represents the folder and file structure?

- test (folder)
- file3.txt (file)

and then querying on the "test" folder should give

- subfolder (folder)
- file.txt (file)
- file2.txt (file)

Every item in the table knows if it is a directory or a file.

Comment: Your first questions.. what do you mean exactly please?

Comment: Your expected results are unclear. Can you rephrase what it is you're looking for?

Comment: How a folder is different from a file in your table? Is it only by the fact that it always contains other files/folders? Or is it a folder because it has no name extension? I mean, if you have two rows like `\folder\subfolder\a`, `\folder\subfolder\b`, and one is a file and the other is a folder, how would you know which one is which?

Comment: you should have a precondition like 'folders always end with \' or 'files always have extension'

Comment: @Christian Sparre: Sorry, it seems I overlooked the bit `Every item in the table knows if it is a directory or a file.` Don't know what you mean, though. Are you talking about some `IsDirectory` column?

Comment: @Andriy M, yes there is an IsDirectory column on each row :)

Comment: @Christian Sparre: Good, and I find it especially convenient that it is present on each row (just joking). I've managed to post a solution having made some assumptions which you might refute, so please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution where it is assumed the table has a column indicating whether an item is a folder. Folder items in the table should not end with '\'.

```
DECLARE @dir varchar(300);
SET @dir = '\test\';

SELECT
  dir_item = CASE diritem WHEN '' THEN '.' ELSE dir_item END,
  is_folder
FROM (
  SELECT
    dir_item,
    is_folder
  FROM (
    SELECT
      dir_item = STUFF(path_item, 1, LEN(@dir), ''),
      is_folder
    FROM paths
    WHERE SUBSTRING(path, 1, LEN(@dir)) = @dir
  ) s
  WHERE CHARINDEX('\', dir_item) = 0
) s
ORDER BY is_folder DESC, dir_item;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andriy, I think that will do exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

see this blog about [convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php).
The example covers a similar problem and provides a solution in php.
(doesn't mean you have to do it with php but you may adopt the idea/algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

BW's PHP link would be good to check out, but if you'd like to stick to SQL, try this UDF.  Given an input string, it will split it on a specified separator, returning one row per item.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@Input VARCHAR(MAX), @Separator CHAR(1))
  RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
  WITH A AS
    (
    SELECT 1 AS Sequence, CAST(1 AS BIGINT) AS StartChar, CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Input) AS EndChar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Sequence + 1, EndChar + 1, CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Input, EndChar + 1)
    FROM A
    WHERE EndChar > 0
    )
  SELECT
    Sequence,
    SUBSTRING(@Input, StartChar, CASE WHEN EndChar = 0 THEN LEN(@Input) - EndChar ELSE EndChar - StartChar END) AS Value
  FROM
    A
```

Example: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('C:\Dir\File.ext', '\')` returns:

```
Sequence Value
1        C:
2        Dir
3        File.ext
```

This isn't a complete solution, but hopefully it will help!